# correct degrees of freedom

Tags: r, regression, degrees-of-freedom, bic

I want to compare two models via BIC in a regression. My conditional error distribution is gaussian. The existing model (not changeable) is:

model 1:
`y~Z+I(Z^2)+I(Z^2)+I(Z^3)+I(Z^4)`

where Z is actually the log ratio of two covariates x1 and x2 : `Z=log(x1/x2)`

now I want to compare this model to a new model defined as

model 2:
`y ~ x1+x2+x3+x4+x5+x6+x7`

Now when calculating BIC or AIC the degrees of freedom based on the parameters estimated are 6  for model 1 (5+1).
while for model 2 the df is 8 (7+1)

but actually model 1 is also based on 2 covariates in each term, so a comparison that way is not that fair,
is there a corretion for this?

Comment: You lose degrees of freedom due to estimation of parameters, just like you said. This is not 1:1 dependent on the number of variables in your model, so I dont think you need a correction. Example: estimating y=beta*(x1+x2) = beta*(x3) will both result in estimation of one estimator beta*.

Comment: but say I want to create a model that maximizes the information gained from the least information I put in beforehand, then creating a parameter like Z will include twice the info than a model with say only x1 although both fit only 1 parameter. maybe model 1 be rewritten somehow say instead of y~log(x1/x2) ... to y~log(x1)-log(x2)... but not sure if this will give the same output as now two parameters are estimated with uncertainty...